# How do I prevent the user from being able to add names that already exist?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

The handleSubmit() function is where I am preventing the user from adding an existing user but it does not work. If the name added exists in the persons list then an alert should pop up.

EDIT: Link to my code https://github.com/yudhiesh1997/fullstackopen/tree/master/part2/phonebook

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import { v4 as uuidv4 } from "uuid";
const PersonForm = ({ addPerson, persons }) => {
  const [info, setInfo] = useState({
    name: "",
    number: "",
    id: "",
  });

  const handleInputChange = (event) => {
    setInfo({ ...info, [event.target.name]: event.target.value });
  };
  const handleSubmit = (event) => {
    const form = event.target;
    event.preventDefault();
    if (event.target.name === persons.map((person) => person.name)) {
      alert("Name exist");
    }
    addPerson({
      ...info,
      id: uuidv4(),
    });
    setInfo({ ...info, name: "", number: "" });
    form.reset();
  };

  return (
    <div>
      <form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
        Name: <input type="text" name="name" onChange={handleInputChange} />
        <br />
        Number:
        <input type="number" name="number" onChange={handleInputChange} />
        <button type="submit">Add</button>
      </form>
    </div>
  );
};

export default PersonForm;
```

Comment: [.map()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) doesn't return a single value...

Comment: Does it return a new array of the name's in persons?

Comment: yes it does. So you can't compare an array to a single name. You need to check each name individually.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok so thank you for pointing out the mistake of comparing an array to a single name

This works

```
const handleSubmit = (event) => {
    const form = event.target;
    event.preventDefault();
    if (persons.map((person) => person.name === info.name).length > 0) {
      alert("Name exist");
      form.reset();
      return;
    }
    addPerson({
      ...info,
      id: uuidv4(),
    });
    setInfo({ name: "", number: "" });
    form.reset();
  };
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to determine if your user exists in array

````
    const form = event.target;
    event.preventDefault();
    if (persons.some((person) => person.name === event.target.name)) {
      alert("Name exist");
      return
    }
    addPerson({
      ...info,
      id: uuidv4(),
    });
    setInfo({ ...info, name: "", number: "" });
    form.reset();
  };```
````

Comment: Did that but no alert pops up and returns a delete button without any name or number below the other contacts that were added previously.